# How to put a subscript in the center of two letters

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have the following code
`\sum_{i<j}^{}\sum Cov(X_i, X_j)` which renders

[image: formula rendering]

How can I move the `i<j` subscript to the center underneath the two sigmas (which will result in a "shift")? Preference will be given to the simplest solution.

Comment: Use `\mathop{\sum\sum}_{i<j}`.

Comment: Didn't find the similar question on here. Werner, post your answer, I prefer it over defining a new operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\mathop` to stack symbols under (as a subscript) or over (as a superscript) math operators:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\[
  \mathop{\sum\sum}_{i < j} \text{Cov}(X_i, X_j)
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\doublesum}{\sum\sum}

\begin{document}

\[\doublesum_{i<j} \Cov(X_i, X_j)\]

\end{document}
```

[image]